# How can I project an oscilloscope display on to a wall screen

Tags: oscilloscope, display

In the autumn I will be giving a talk to my local amateur radio club and I would like to illustrate it with live displays on my oscilloscope projected on to a large wall screen. I have tried this before with my Rigol DS1052E using their own software, Ultrascope, to get the display on to a PC, with the well established "blue socket" to project from the PC on to the big screen. Unfortunately there were two big problems. One is that there is a one or two seconds delay between changes on the oscilloscope and the PC screen, and the second is that use of Ultrascope cuts off the normal controls on the 'scope and transfers them to rather non-intuitive graphics on the PC screen. It was a complete flop, I could not control the scope in the tension of delivering the talk and the display that I relied on was a disaster.

Finding some programming examples on the 'net, I have written my own program to copy the 'scope data to the PC via a USB link, but I still find that it suffers from the same inevitable problems of delays and losing the 'scope controls, as does Ultrascope.

I have also tried using a webcam, a good(ish) one, Logitech HD720p to view the display, size 4.5 by 3.5 inches, but it suffers from poor definition at that close range; I could use it but it would be a last resort.

Please, has anyone solved this problem, or have any pertinent advice to overcome it? the purse is shallow, any solution needs to be reasonably cheap. If I buy another webcam, which would be the best?

Comment: Well next time you're buying a scope, get one with VGA or DVI out. :) As for your question, what kind of equipment do you have available? Also what do you mean by "poor definition"? Is it focusing problem with the camera? Lack of resolution (but that seems strange to me)? What kind of setup do you have for holding camera in front of the screen?

Comment: I would ask Rigol.